# How can I make this method shorter and easier to follow?

Tags: c#

It's long, repetitive, and hard to follow.

```
    private void Map(object x, JToken json)
    {
        var objType = x.GetType();
        var props = objType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite).ToList();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var type = prop.PropertyType;

            var name = prop.Name;
            var value = json[name];
            var actualName = name;

            if (value == null)
            {
                // try camel cased name
                actualName = name.ToCamelCase(Culture);
                value = json[actualName];
            }

            if (value == null)
            {
                // try lower cased name
                actualName = name.ToLower(Culture);
                value = json[actualName];
            }

            if (value == null)
            {
                // try name with underscores
                actualName = name.AddUnderscores();
                value = json[actualName];
            }

            if (value == null)
            {
                // try name with underscores with lower case
                actualName = name.AddUnderscores().ToLower(Culture);
                value = json[actualName];
            }

            if (value == null)
            {
                // try name with dashes
                actualName = name.AddDashes();
                value = json[actualName];
            }

            if (value == null)
            {
                // try name with dashes with lower case
                actualName = name.AddDashes().ToLower(Culture);
                value = json[actualName];
            }

            if (value == null || value.Type == JTokenType.Null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // check for nullable and extract underlying type
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                type = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }

            if (type.IsPrimitive)
            {
                // no primitives can contain quotes so we can safely remove them
                // allows converting a json value like {"index": "1"} to an int
                var tmpVal = value.AsString().Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                prop.SetValue(x, tmpVal.ChangeType(type), null);
            }
            else if (type.IsEnum)
            {
                string raw = value.AsString();
                var converted = Enum.Parse(type, raw, false);
                prop.SetValue(x, converted, null);
            }
            else if (type == typeof(Uri))
            {
                string raw = value.AsString();
                var uri = new Uri(raw, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                prop.SetValue(x, uri, null);
            }
            else if (type == typeof(string))
            {
                string raw = value.AsString();
                prop.SetValue(x, raw, null);
            }
            else if (type == typeof(DateTime) || type == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
            {
                DateTime dt;
                if (DateFormat.HasValue())
                {
                    var clean = value.AsString();
                    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(clean, DateFormat, Culture);
                }
                else if (value.Type == JTokenType.Date)
                {
                    dt = value.Value<DateTime>().ToUniversalTime();
                }
                else
                {
                    // try parsing instead
                    dt = value.AsString().ParseJsonDate(Culture);
                }

                if (type == typeof(DateTime))
                    prop.SetValue(x, dt, null);
                else if (type == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
                    prop.SetValue(x, (DateTimeOffset)dt, null);
            }
            else if (type == typeof(Decimal))
            {
                var dec = Decimal.Parse(value.AsString(), Culture);
                prop.SetValue(x, dec, null);
            }
            else if (type == typeof(Guid))
            {
                string raw = value.AsString();
                var guid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(raw) ? Guid.Empty : new Guid(raw);
                prop.SetValue(x, guid, null);
            }
            else if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                var genericTypeDef = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (genericTypeDef == typeof(List<>))
                {
                    var list = BuildList(type, value.Children());
                    prop.SetValue(x, list, null);
                }
                else if (genericTypeDef == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
                {
                    var keyType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                    // only supports Dict<string, T>()
                    if (keyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        var dict = BuildDictionary(type, value.Children());
                        prop.SetValue(x, dict, null);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // nested property classes
                    var item = CreateAndMap(type, json[actualName]);
                    prop.SetValue(x, item, null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // nested property classes
                var item = CreateAndMap(type, json[actualName]);
                prop.SetValue(x, item, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am downvoting this because there's no description of what the code does, it is basically a "copy-paste" question. Please at least include a short description of what the code does.

Comment: I'm not a c# programmer. However, one thing I noticed is that you have multiple if statements who all share the condition value == null. Why do you need like 4 if statements with the same condition? Why not simple take all the blocks from the 4 statements and put them into one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To expand on Carl's answer a little more, this would be a good candidate for the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). You could add each case as a strategy callback:

```
private var toValue(var name, params Func<var, var>[] matchingStrategies)
{
    foreach(var strategy in matchingStrategies)
    {
        value = json[strategy(name)];

        if (value != null)
            return value;
    }

    return null;
}

// usage:

var name = prop.Name;

var value = toValue(name,
    (n) => n.ToCamelCase(Culture),
    (n) => n.ToLower(Culture),
    (n) => n.AddUnderscores(),
    (n) => n.AddUnderscores().ToLower(Culture),
    (n) => n.AddDashes(),
    (n) => n.AddDashes().ToLower(),
    (n) => n.ToCamelCase(Culture));
```

So you're passing a list of matching strategies in order of execution, with the function returning the result of the first successful matching strategy.

Or you could encapsulate each strategy into its own class - which would enable you to unit test them individually.

Comment: I'm pretty sure C# doesn't support `var` as a return type, or as part of a `Func` declaration.

Comment: Fair enough, if you're feeling particularly ambitious you could also probably replace the `foreach` loop with a `where` and `FirstOrDefault` linq query.  Would make the intent of the code a bit clearer.

Answer (score 11):

Step 1: extract the body of the loop into its own method that takes prop as a parameter.  Now your primary method looks like

```
private void Map(object x, JToken json)
    {
        var objType = x.GetType();
        var props = objType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite).ToList();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
             process(prop);
        }
    }
```

and that's a good start.

Now we spend a good amount of code getting the value from the name.  Extract that:

```
private var toValue(var name)
    {
        var value = json[name];
        if (value != null) return value;

        value = json[name.ToCamelCase(Culture)];
        if (value != null) return value;

        value = json[name.ToLower(Culture)];
        if (value != null) return value;

        value = json[name.AddUnderscores()];
        if (value != null) return value;

        value = json[name.AddUnderscores().ToLower(Culture)];
        if (value != null) return value;

        value = json[name.AddDashes()];
        if (value != null) return value;

        value = json[name.AddDashes().ToLower(Culture)];
        if (value != null) return value;

        value = json[name.ToCamelCase(Culture)];
        if (value != null) return value;

        return null;
    }
```

Notice how much cleaner this section can be, because we've extracted it.  We simply return the value when it's non-null, rather than checking over and over again whether it's null.  And this extracted method has a clear single purpose; if you came up with another variant of how to process the name to make it a valid key, it would be clear where to put it.  Smaller methods pay off in many ways.

I think that is a good start and you should be able to see where to go from here.

Comment: I like it. I just think there's something more to be done from here. For example : http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Answer (score 5):

I'd also drop the `.ToList()` on this line:

```
var props = objType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite).ToList();
```

because props is only used in one place, to be enumerated over in the `foreach` loop.

Calling `ToList` forces the computer to loop all the way through the collection, just to convert it into a list.

Then on the very next line it loops all the way through a second time. Why do all that work just to get a list?

The code would behave the same, only faster, if we just loop over the collection once

Comment: Why would you drop the .ToList()?

Comment: @JeffVanzella, because `props` is only used in one place, to be enumerated over in the foreach loop.  Calling `ToList` forces the computer to loop all the way through the collection, just to convert it into a list.  Then on the very next like it loops all the way through a second time.  Why do all that work just to get a list?  The code would behave the same, only faster, if we just loop over the collection once.

Comment: Just wanted you to elaborate :)

Answer (score -4):

I personally try to stay away from using the `var` keyword, as sometimes it tends to make code unreadable for example `var result = ReturnResult();` when reading this I don't really know what the type it is at a glance. And try to initialize your variables outside of the `foreach` loop. I would normally declare all my variables at the top of the method and use them later on if needed.

Comment: the problem is not var, but the naming.